# iOS - Is Swift bundled with the app binary or the operating system

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, deployment, binaryfiles

I'm curious if Swift is natively a part of the iOS 7/8/9 operating system or if the application binary carries the swift runtime with it (potentially increasing binary size)?

I'm similarly curious if this is the case for Objective-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Swift runtime library embedded in the app to ensure compatibility as you can see [here](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=2).

Comment: It says there that they would include the runtime in the OS in a year or two. Do you know if anything has changed since the release of iOS 9?

Comment: [This](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4891?q=swift%20incl) is the only relevant piece of info i could find on the apple developer forums. Your best bet would be e-mailing apple directly.

Answer (score 1):

If your app has Swift code, you can unzip your .ipa file and explore the contents of the .app folder. You will see that the app bundle is including the Swift runtime library

[image]

So yes, it is increasing the app size by a few MB